# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon (Ubunutu 16.04.5) Xenial

Tags: 16.04, docker

I recently installed docker following instructions outlined here:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

I know this question has been asked a lot on different forums but most dont refer to my very basic problem and the others have solutions that didnt work.

The installation finished without any errors but when I enter the command:

```
$sudo docker run hello-world
```

I get the following error:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

'docker' is in the list of groups for the current user and I tried the command with docker running and stopped.

I have tried the steps outlined in the post-installation steps here:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Which are essentially the same steps outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon?rq=1

With no luck

When I enter:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

I get the output:

```
Running in chroot, ignoring request
```